# Target what svg compressor option messes up file for sketch 3

Tags: vector, svg, sketch-app, file-size, compression

I am using https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg to compress my svg image, its pretty good at what it does, but after running image through it, sketch 3 messes it up and it looks like this:

[image]

Where as it originally looked like this

[image]

Now the compressor I mentioned above has quiet a hand full of different options and I am pretty sure one of them or combination of few can be disabled to make svg look good in skecth 3 again, I tried disabling them one by one, but still got this result. do you have any idea on which options can be disabled to prevent this from happening i.e. is there anything that sketch 3 relies on there?

Comment: It may not help but I just noticed today that they released a new version of Sketch with some updates to SVG import/export so updating the software may solve your problem

Comment: The 'messed up' image actually looks AWEEEEESOME!

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter yeh :D unfortunately unusable in my project, but  I can see how it can be used to make some fractal image!

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the skill to fix what you posted but I would really like to know the error that made it occur and use it for my project, for which it would be totally awesome!